# Microsoft Excel: Identifying rows that contain matching values (on the same row)

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016

I would like to identify rows where the values in three columns are the same, irrespective of what the value actually is (the match is enough).

I've tried some alternatives using **COUNTIF** function, but with no luck [e.g. =`COUNTIF(B4=C4=D4; 1; 2)`].

In the following example I would like to identify *Person3* and *Person6*, since they have matching data in these cells. But all other persons should not be identified, including *Person 2* who has only two matching numbers.

[image]

A new column on the right might return either a number value (e.g. **1** if match found) or value **TRUE**. If relevant: there will be other data in the spreadsheet too, this is just a simplified example.

Answer (score 3):

Here is one formula you can use:
`=COUNTIF(C2:D2,B2)=COLUMNS(C2:D2)`

How it works:
`COUNTIF` compares column values to first column and count the ones which are the same, if all are the same then it'll be equal to total number of cells in that range (`COLUMNS`).

[image]

Comment: Seems to work, thanks! As I don't quite understand the syntax: what does it actually do?

Comment: I'm happy it works, please see my update.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to suggest you something different formula,,

=IF(COUNTIF(B2:D2,B2)=3,"All Dup",IF(COUNTIF(B2:D2,B2)=2,"2 Dupl","1 Only"))

Since you have only 3 values and you are testing duplicates in the row, this formula is looking more meaning Full.

Comment: user8105 ,, No for Row number 6 &10 you get "All Dupl" and for row 9,, 2 Dupl. Better you try this Formula in Col. F.